# How to link jquery to an external js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to link jquery to an external js file, but I can´t get it to work. This is my full html. I have put jquery before the js file, as you can see. I also tryed to link both the jquery and js in the body after the div, but that didn't work either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css-teachers/lessons- teacher.css"/>
<script src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript-teachers/lessons-teacher.js"></script>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>HOME</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="box1"> <a href="page2.html"/></div>
 <div id="box2"> <a href="page3.html"/></div>
 <div id="box3"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box4"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box5"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box6"> <a href="#"/></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

My js works if I put it into the body like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css-teachers/lessons- teacher.css"/>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>HOME</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="box1"> <a href="page2.html"/></div>
 <div id="box2"> <a href="page3.html"/></div>
 <div id="box3"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box4"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box5"> <a href="#"/></div>
 <div id="box6"> <a href="#"/></div>

<script src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$("#box1").click(function() {
window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
return false;
}); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your folder structure

Comment: When you put the JS inline, is it after the #box1 has been defined? If so, your problem may be that you're trying to bind the click event to the element in the head, before the element has been defined. Try moving both includes to the bottom of your page (just before closing the body tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad my comment above helped.

Just wanted to mention that, since you're using jQuery, you can also put the code in your external file in the following code block to prevent it from executing until all page elements are rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box1").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

More info: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Will do, tnx for that. Do you also happen to know how to make a drop down menu appear after a specific value in another dropdown menu has been selected?

Comment: When you say, "drop down menu," are you talking about something similar to populating one Select Element with values based on a selection made in another Select Element? Or do you have a specific menu structure already built out you can provide (maybe in a Fiddle)?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/94cz5su0 So only when appointment is being selected the  second dropdown menu should appear

Comment: See if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/s561ao1L/

Of note: In order to use jQuery in a fiddle, you must select a version of the jQuery library in the first Select Element under "Frameworks & Extension" on the upper-left of fiddle the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you link your script inside the tag `<head> </head>` maybe you have to include the type:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
```

like the same way you did with your home.js